# How to make the histograms 'touch' in pylab?

Tags: python, plot, histogram

So I made a program that does what I need, mainly plots histogram from my data, but I have a few issues with it:

Here's the program:

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
from __future__ import division
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = loadtxt("mioni.txt", int)

nuz = len(data)
nsmp = 20
duz = int(nuz/nsmp)

L = []

for i1 in range(0,nsmp):
    suma = 0
    for i2 in range(0,duz):
        suma += data[i1*duz+i2]
    L.append(suma)

print L


plt.hist(L, 20, normed=1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel('t(\mu s)')
plt.ylabel('Broj događaja')
plt.axis([0,10,0,300])
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

EDIT: so I managed to deal with the ugly sums, but now my histograms don't work :(
Data is here: `http://dropcanvas.com/kqjem`

What's wrong? I get tons of errors and python crashes :\

Comment: The heart of your question is "how do I get the histograms to touch". I'm editing your title and question to reflect this.

Comment: I've also removed the part about non-linear fitting, not only is that a second question (and can be asked as such), you don't give us any real example data to help you with.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask that separately, but even the histogram part isn't that troubling, as I am capable of drawing it. The fact that is troubling me is, how to make these sums arbitrary on the fact how many points I take as a division. Right now I have to manually write each sum, which is tedious...

Comment: Like I said, ask that as a separate question (you can link this one to it). StackOverflow works best for a singular _answerable_ question (code review is _not_ part of that). That said, sums can be avoid by calling `pylab.hist` as in my answer.

Comment: Oh, so I don't need the sums... Well, I can still use the sums if I want to find discrete points for plotting in origin :D 
EDIT: And I tried with my data set I've given below, and it doesn't work :\

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from having a discrete data set, it looks like you set the `bins` parameter to something that doesn't fit. Use the `pylab.hist` parameter `histtype="stepfilled"` to get them to touch without the lines. Here are a few examples:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Sample data
X1 = np.random.exponential(1.0,size=5000)
X2 = [int(z) for z in X1]

plt.subplot(221)
plt.hist(X1,bins=50)
plt.title('Continuous Data')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.hist(X2,bins=50)
plt.title('Discrete Data')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.hist(X2,histtype='stepfilled')
plt.title('Discrete Data Filled')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `numpy.histogram`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

or `matplotlib.pyplot.hist`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

for example:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=20)
```

Comment: if you post your data file somewhere, I will try to find the unknown reason.